# Any idea with font-size of 1.05em/1.2em?

Tags: css, font-size

I saw a vid on Youtube and noticed that the font-size of body is 1.05em/1.2em.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvWbY.png

However, I tried this setting like `1.4em/1em` vs. `1.4em`. It seems to be a little bigger for `1.4em/1em`, but there's no difference between `1.4em/1.4em` or things like this. Any idea with this kind of setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is font-size/line-height.

e.g. 1.4em/1em is 1.4em font-size and 1em line-height

full css syntax for font is:

```
font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family|caption|icon|menu|message-box|small-caption|status-bar|initial|inherit;
```

Comment: I got it! Didn't see it on w3school. Thanks!

Comment: @ChenghuaYang don't use w3school, use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) instead. If you have a question about an HTML element/attribute, a CSS property or a JS function and a lot more look to MDN first. Simply Google _font mdn_ and the first result will be MDN's CSS font property page.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Hmm... just curious, why use MDN instead? Is it faster in update? (I'm new to web development. :D)